# Group dictionary by key and find max value

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a dictionary with datetime as key and a list of IDs as value. It is actually the number of active users for each time of the day.

The dictionary looks like:

```
2016-03-09 12:13:24 [34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L, 35167L, 35180L]
2016-03-09 12:16:49 [34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L, 35167L, 35187L]
2016-03-09 12:17:14 [34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L, 35167L, 35187L]
2016-03-09 12:21:39 [34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L, 35167L]
2016-03-09 12:22:01 [34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L, 35188L]
2016-03-09 12:23:08 [34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L, 35188L]
2016-03-09 12:23:37 [35191L, 34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L]
2016-03-09 12:24:05 [35191L, 34941L, 34943L, 35183L, 35028L, 35031L, 35081L, 35091L]
```

What I want to do is to make a dictionary which will contain the maximum number of users for each day. Something like:

```
2016-03-07: 25
2016-03-08: 38
2016-03-09: 12
2016-03-10: 29
```

EDIT: I want to find the peak of each day.

So I need to find the length of the list of values then group by date of the key and finally find the maximum value of the group.

Finding the length of the list is the easy part with something like:

```
for time, user_id in sorted(users_by_time.iteritems()):
    user_by_time[time] = len(user_id)
```

But I am struggling with the grouping.

How can both grouping and max calculation be done and ideally in the most effective/pythonic way?

Comment: Keys of input dict are datetime.datetime objects? or strings?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir, they are datetime.datetime objects

Comment: It'd be useful if you actually posted your `dict` in the syntax of a `dict` so that users can copy and paste it directly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the peaks of each day is quite easy:

```
from collections import defaultdict

max_count_by_day = defaultdict(int)
for dt, user_ids in users_by_time.iteritems():
    d = dt.date()
    max_count_by_day[d] = max(max_count_by_day[d], len(user_ids))
```

---

For number of distinct users per day, use a `defaultdict(set)`:

```
users_in_day = defaultdict(set)
for dt, user_ids in users_by_time.iteritems():
    users_in_day[dt.date()].update(user_ids)
```

Then flatten the dictionary into another of `date: count`:

```
usercount_per_day = {d: len(user_ids) for d, user_ids in users_in_day.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

For grouping you can do

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in my_dict:
    b[key.date()] += len(value)
```

Then convert to list and sort

```
output = sorted(zip(output.keys(), output.values()))
```

Comment: I don't know if just adding up lengths is a good idea, because what if the same user visits at different times in the same day? Do we want `34943L` to count as six users because he visited six times?

Comment: @Kevin yeah! sorry! forgot that :)

Comment: @Antti's answer is more valid in that case.