# How to find max value for each category in a dictionary

Tags: python

Hi needing some help with my code here.

`for i, (l,v) in enumerate(dict(list(zip(estate_2019,resale_2019))).items()):`

estate_2019 is a list of estates (25 unique names but over a few thousand entries) while resale_2019 is the corresponding sale prices (few thousand entries). I'm looking to find the max sale value and the estate name for each of the estate in estate_2019, so it'll be a list of 25 estates with the max resale price.

both estate_2019 and resale_2019 are extracted from a csv. resale_2019 has been formatted as a float.

`print(l,v)`
gives me the list of estates but I'm not sure how python retrieves the sale prices. Appreciate any help here. Also, I can only use numpy as this is a homework assignment.

Comment: Can you provide a small set of example data that can be used to run your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try: [Group dictionary by key and find max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916618/group-dictionary-by-key-and-find-max-value)
or
https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-max-value-in-a-dictionary-in-python

Although i am not sure how to use numpy to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to store a *list* of all the prices against each estate as a key. For example using a default dictionary you could do that easily as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

prop_dict = defaultdict(list)

for est, price in zip(estate_2019, sale_2019):
    prop_dict[est].append(price)
```

Once you have that dictionary with corresponding price lists, you can get the maximum price value per key by using `np.max()` or even python's native `max()` function if the lists are not too big.

```
max_vals = {estate: np.max(np.array(value)) for estate, value in prop_dict.items()}
```